# Empty a select if the option was already selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I have a button that append a row with a select with its options. I gave those select a class (".nuevaDescripcionProducto"). The select has its first option (with the value: "Select an option" or whatever) and the rest of the options are added when I click the button to add the new row. Ok, what I want is: To go back to the first option if I select an option that is already selected in another row. Maybe you could get it more clear by looking a the picture:

[image: example]

This is my code so far:

```
$(".formularioVenta").on("change", "select.nuevaDescripcionProducto", function() {

var nombreProducto = $(this).val();

var productos = $(".nuevaDescripcionProducto");

for (var i = 0; i < productos.length; i++) {

    var x = $(productos[i]).val();

    if(nombreProducto == x) {

        $(nombreProducto).val();
    }
}

})
```

I think most of what is needed its done. But I would hugely appreciate any help for you. Thanks.

Comment: Its not clear what you want. You want to remove an option from the dropdown if its already selected in the previous row ? If yes then you need to provide HTML and complete relevant to that.

Comment: Hi, AlwaysHelping. Yes I wanted to do that, but somebody gave me another alternative: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/389565/cambiar-el-value-de-un-select-si-el-option-ya-est%c3%a1-seleccionado/389578?noredirect=1#comment697849_389578

Comment: Its in the Spanish StackOverflow